# Check value of form input and give alert if it is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm making a quiz and am trying to check for empty input fields when the "next" button is clicked. If someone doesn't answer a question, then I want to give an alert and prevent them from going to the next question.

For some reason, with my code, on the second question, it will give the "no response" alert, even if you enter a response on the second try. I can't figure out why.

Here is the part of the code that raises the alert:

```
$("button").click(function() {
  // check for empty input
  var inputVal = $.trim($(".question:visible input").val());
  console.log("The value of the input is: " + inputVal);
  if (inputVal.length == 0 || inputVal == "") {
    alert("Please enter a response.");
  } else {

  position++;
  quesNum = position + 1; 

  // hide previous question
  $(".question").hide();

  // show next question 
  if (position < totalQues) {
    $(".question").eq(position).show();
    $(".questionNumber").text("Question " + quesNum + " of " +
      totalQues);
  } else {

    // at the end of the questions, hide the questions and show the results
    $(".question, .questionNumber, button").hide();

    // calculate risk percentage
    calculatePerc();

    //show results template
    $(".results").show();
    showResults();
  }
}
}); // end button click function
```

And here is my JS Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/amykirst/mpjg2vbk/

What can I do to make the dropdown alert work properly, so that it lets you proceed if you enter a response on the second try?

Comment: Thank you. That worked for most. The only questions it didn't work for are the radio buttons. Do I need to do something different for those?

Answer (score 0):

you must know that a dropdown (select) is not a input tag is a select tag, you are searching for an input but the dropdown is a select not an input

Answer (score 0):

this happens because in the second question, you haven't used an `input`, it's a `select` tag that can be found with a simple if statement: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mpjg2vbk/4/)**

```
if($(".question:visible input").length==0){
        inputVal=$(".question:visible select").val();
    }
```

**A suggestion:**

I believe it would be much easier and more efficient to use `switch()` instead of using that many `if()` statements inside your code.

**UPDATE:**

The `radio` problem happens because for `radio` inputs you must get the value of the `checked` radio. here is the fix of it, you need to add another `if()` statement to your code: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mpjg2vbk/7/)**

```
if($(".question:visible input").length==0){
        inputVal=$(".question:visible select").val();
    }
    else if($(".question:visible input[type=radio]").length>0){
        inputVal=$(".question:visible input[type=radio]:checked").val();
        if($(".question:visible input[type=radio]:checked").length==0) inputVal='';
    }
```

**UPDATE2:**

you need to add another `if()` statement: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mpjg2vbk/16/)**

```
if($(".question:visible input").length==0){
        inputVal=$(".question:visible select").val();
        if(inputVal==null) inputVal='';
    }
    else if($(".question:visible input[type=radio]").length>0){
        inputVal=$(".question:visible input[type=radio]:checked").val();
        if($(".question:visible input[type=radio]:checked").length==0) inputVal='';
    }
```

Comment: Changing to the input selector works for most but the radio questions. Although the jquery documentation looks like it says it works for radio buttons. I've updated the jsfiddle. I didn't know about switch(). I'll look into it.

Comment: It's saying that the value of the radio buttons is "Yes" even if nothing is checked.

Comment: I checked out your demo. It doesn't look like it works with the select dropdowns. If I enter no value, it won't give an alert.